# Could not load type 'DotNetNuke.Web.DDRMenu.SolPartSkinObject'

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-8

I have a set up of code which are developed in DNN 8.when I am trying to run this code from visual studio 2013 I found these errors.
"Could not load type 'DotNetNuke.Web.DDRMenu.SolPartSkinObject'
 and 'Could not load type 'DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.SolPartActions'

.so How to solve these errors.I had try my best but i couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Did you register the TagName?

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="SOLPARTMENU" Src="~/DesktopModules/DDRMenu/SolPartMenu.ascx" %>
```

And then on the Skin page

```
<dnn:SOLPARTMENU runat="server" id="dnnSOLPARTMENU" />
```

Comment: `DotNetNuke.SolpartMenuNavigationProvider.dll` and `SolpartWebControls.dll` should be present in folder `/bin/Providers`

Comment: yes its there.but why i am getting error like "The type or namespace name 'Vendors' does not exist in the namespace and "The type or namespace name 'BannerController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?".